# Comparing a word in a list to a word in a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that loops through a list and checks a file to see if that word is in there. At first, the file is read and then if a word is found, it breaks out of that loop. With the remaining lines in the file after that word is found, I want to compare with the list. The code below isn't working. It just breaks out of the loop and doesn't find the word. 
Thanks for your assistance.

```
def readFile():
with open("file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "Hello" in line:
            break
    for word in mylist:
        if word in myfile:
           print(word + "found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need another `for line in myfile` loop. You can't do `if word in myfile` to check the entire file, you still need to loop over each line.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "Hello" in line:
            break
    for line in myfile:
        for word in mylist:
            if word in line:
                print(word + "found")
```

Note that this could print the same word multiple times. If you don't want that you'll need to track which words you've already seen.

```
already_seen = set()        

for line in myfile:
    for word in mylist:
        if word in already_seen:
            continue

        if word in line:
            print(word + "found")
            already_seen.add(word)
```

Comment: Or, for the second part, the more simple (and probably practical esp. for a small list)... `seen = set(mylist).intersection(myfile)` - then print at the end...